# Unity If & else statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have 5 different objects and every time I click on a specific object they should be placed in order. Instead of being put in order, it seems to skip the first and goes to the second. So instead of going to check1, it goes straight to check2.

This is my code:

```
if (IsBehindHeld == true)
    {
        Vector3 MousePos;
        MousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(MousePos);


        if (Check1.transform.childCount != 1)
        {
            this.gameObject.transform.position = Check1.transform.position;
            _rb2.isKinematic = true;
            locked = true;

            this.transform.parent = Check1.transform;

        }

        else
        {
            if (Check2.transform.childCount != 1 )
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.position = Check2.transform.position;
                _rb2.isKinematic = true;
                locked = true;

                this.transform.parent = Check2.transform;

            }

            else
            {
                if (Check3.transform.childCount != 1)
                {
                    this.gameObject.transform.position = Check3.transform.position;
                    _rb2.isKinematic = true;
                    locked = true;

                    this.transform.parent = Check3.transform;

                }

                else
                {

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does ```Check1``` have any child objects before this runs?

Comment: No, No child objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post more information about the check colliders, the object hierarchy and components each has to understand more. Also, it is easier to read if you try with else if:

```
if (IsBehindHeld == true)
        {
            Vector3 MousePos;
            MousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(MousePos);


            if (Check1.transform.childCount != 1)
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.position = Check1.transform.position;
                _rb2.isKinematic = true;
                locked = true;

                this.transform.parent = Check1.transform;

            }

            else if (Check2.transform.childCount != 1)
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.position = Check2.transform.position;
                _rb2.isKinematic = true;
                locked = true;

                this.transform.parent = Check2.transform;

            }
            else if (Check3.transform.childCount != 1)
            {
                this.gameObject.transform.position = Check3.transform.position;
                _rb2.isKinematic = true;
                locked = true;

                this.transform.parent = Check3.transform;

            }
        }
```

Multiple else if statements can be used after an if statement. It will only be executed when the if condition evaluates to false. So, either if or one of the else if statements can be executed, but not both. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: ```else if...``` and ```else { if... }``` are exactly the same thing. (But it definitely looks better!)

Comment: I tried with a else if and it just skips straight to check5 now?

Comment: It still seems to jump from 1 -> 2 -> 1 in a mini second, honestly it's about to drive me crazy

Comment: It must be your "Check" logic then. You should try to see if your colliders are not overlapping, or maybe you can add boolean property to check if one object was clicked, and put it to false until the process is done. Try explaining that part a bit more, to see if we can help :)

Comment: That sounds like you're running the check on mouse held rather than mouse down.  Add some debug.logs to each of the ifs and see how many run when you click once.